# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c# richtextbox and datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, richtextbox

I am receiving this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I am trying my code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
       {
        rtb.Text = rtb.Text+ dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
               }
```

Where rtb is a richtextbox and dgv is a datagridview with 4 columns . Ty for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: One (or more) of the following is `null`: `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0]`, `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value`.  Run the app in the debugger and see which is null.

Comment: It could really be a few things, fire up the debugger and if you cannot do that, then break down each item into a variable temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to start your `for` loop from 0 and set the upper limit to `RowCount -1` i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount - 1; i++)
```

C# uses zero based arrays.